# trying to call method of inner class from outerclass object

Tags: java

I'd like to understand how nested class work.

Say I have an outer class which has a field that is a linked list of inner class object.

Then I create an object of the outer class and tries to call the method defined in the inner class from a node in the linked list in the outer class.

It doesn't seem to work and here is the code:
THE FOLLOWING IS PART OF A HOMEWORK, HEAVILY MODIFIED IT WILL BE, PLEASE DON'T COPY THANK YOU!

```
public class Svec {  
    Node head;
    public class Node {
        public Object data;
        public int index;
        public Node next;

        Node(Object d, int indexx){
            data=d;
            index= indexx;
        }
        public String toString()
        {
            return "Im a node";
        }
        public int getIndex() 
        {
            return this.index;
        }
    }

    public Svec(int length) {
        head= new Node(null,0);
        Node currNode = this.head, prev =null;
        for(int i =1 ;i<length;i++)
        {
            prev=currNode;
            currNode.next = new Node(null,i);
            currNode=currNode.next;
        }
    }
    public Object get(int index) {
        Node currNode = this.head;

        while(currNode != null && currNode.index != index)
            currNode=currNode.next;

        if(currNode != null)
            return currNode;
        else
            return null; 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Svec example1= new Svec(10);

        System.out.println((example1.get(0)).getIndex());
    }

}
```

The last line in the main method is the error.

Answer (score 3):

`Svec.get()` returns an Object. Objects have no getIndex() method. Either change that method to return a Node, or cast it to a Node prior to calling getIndex() on it.

```
Node result = (Node) example1.get(0);
System.out.println(result.getIndex());
```

Answer (score 2):

change `public Object get(int index) {` to `public Node get(int index) {` and it should work.